# Why won't VirtualBox allow me to set a base memory size over 4MB?

Tags: virtualbox

I am using CentOS 5, and have installed virtualbox 4.1 on it. When I try to create a windows XP virtual machine, the VirtualBox options only allow me to set a maximum base memory between 0 and 4 MB. What could be wrong?

I tried searching google and the VirtualBox forum but found no answer.

Comment: are you sure it isnt 4GB?

Comment: Plz check image screenshot https://forums.virtualbox.org/download/file.php?id=9675&sid=f914d511d967e2242d2cef357f5696a5

Comment: I assume you are selecting "XP", what happens if you select other?

Comment: Can you post the host OS system specs, this would help.

Comment: Host os is centos 5 standerd in vps

Comment: Hi Keltari  ,Only windows xp option I selected ,puyt some name,after clicking next this screen came